# How to make non-square edges in Tkinter?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

In order to make one of my programs more aesthetically pleasing  I'm using images to create the boarders, however I want to create a non square boarder so the program looks kinda like this

```
  ___________
 /          /
/__________/
```

How should I go about this?

This is on windows 7, btw.

Edit:

A tried to make a pseudo-edge using transparency however it doesn't come out transparent. For some reason it cam out as a dark grey. I want the red to be the "edge".

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept you are after is called a "shapped window". Search for "tk shaped window" with your favorite search engine. There is a tk extension that claims to support this, though I haven't personally tried it. I presume since it works with tcl/tk it can be made to work with Tkinter since Tkinter uses tcl/tk under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Tkinker, but you could make an image with transparency where you don't want the border, which would make pseudo-slanted edges. There is no way for a window to be non-square however (For a good reason too).

Comment: What software/file type supports transparency?

Comment: "no way" is not correct. There _are_ ways to create non-square windows, just not built-in ways. There are Tk extensions for this which work with Tcl; presumably they work with Tkinter though I haven't tried. Search for "tk shaped windows".